# Передача адреса функции в itoa

Tags: c

Хочу записать в строку адрес функции. Для этого делаю указатель на функцию, который и передам в качестве аргумента:

```
void reverse(char s[])
{
    int i, j;
    char c;

    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s) - 1; i<j; i++, j--) {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
}
void itoa(int n, char s[])
{
    int i, sign;

    if ((sign = n) < 0)  /* record sign */
        n = -(n);          /* make n positive */
    i = 0;
    do {       /* generate digits in reverse order */
        s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';   /* get next digit */
    } while ((n /= 10) > 0);     /* delete it */
    if (sign < 0)
        s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    reverse(s);
}
int kmain()
{

    int (*foo)()=kmain;
    char string[40];
    itoa(foo, string);
```

Но почему-то это неправильно,пишет,что  пишет,что **`аргумент int(*)() несовместим с параметром типа int *`** как исправить ошибку передачи параметра ?

Comment: Что значит "неправильно"? Программа после запуска написала "Это неправильно"?

Comment: @freim, пишет,что аргумент int(*)() несовместим с параметром типа int *

Comment: Как у вас объявлена функция `itoa`?   ` void itoa(int n,  char s[])`
Т.е. вы передаете ей первым аргументом **целое число**. Должны передавать. А вы передаете?    `int (*foo)()=kmain;
    itoa(foo, string);` **Указатель на функцию**. Каковой целым числом можно рассматривать с боооольшой натяжкой. Они могут быть просто несовместимы по размеру - например, 32-битное число и 64-битный указатель. Хотя бы явно приводите его к `int`...\

Comment: Адрес функции не может быть представлен типом. `int` и ни о какой передаче его в ваше `itoa` не может быть и речи.

Comment: @AnT, всё заработало, когда сделал, как сказал Harry

Comment: @Elvin Я не знаю, как у вас там все заработало,так как данное предложение if ((sign = n) < 0) не имеет смысла,, если первый аргумент - это указатель на функцию.

Comment: @Elvin: Вам либо "повезло", либо "показалось".